# Can we get compiler information from an elf binary?

Tags: linux, debugging, executable, elf, compiler

Is there some chance to know how a binary was built, under Linux? (and or other Unix)

Compiler, version, time, flags etc...

I looked at `readelf` and couldn't find much, but there might be other ways at analyzing the binary code/section etc...

Anything you know how to extract?

Answer (score 62):

There isn't a universal way, but you can make an educated guess by looking for things only done by one compiler.

GCC is the easiest; it writes a `.comment` section that contains the GCC version string (the same string you get if you run `gcc --version`). I don't know if there's a way to display it with `readelf`, but with `objdump` it's:

```
objdump -s --section .comment /path/binary
```

---

I just realized I ignored the rest of your question. Flags aren't generally saved anywhere; they would be in a comment section most likely, but I've never seen that done. There's a spot in the COFF header for a timestamp, but there's no equivalent in ELF, so I don't think the compile time is available either

Answer (score 41):

How about:

```
readelf -p .comment a.out
```

Comment: How is this different than Michael's `objdump`? Does it give more information? Available on different platforms? Cleaner output format?

Comment: Cleaner output format.

Answer (score 23):

You can try using the `strings` command. It will create a lot of text output; by checking it you might guess the compiler.

`pubuntu@pubuntu:~$ strings  -a a.out |grep -i gcc

GCC: (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3`

Here I know it's compiled with `gcc` but you can always redirect `strings` output to a file and examine it.

There is one very good utility called [`peid`](http://www.peid.info/) for Windows but I can't find any alternative for it on Linux.

Comment: +1, allows you to see the compilation flags (if gcc)

Answer (score 6):

There are two methods . Both will give the same result

```
objdump -s --section .comment path/to/binary
```

Using readelf command, `readelf -S binary`  will display the 40 section headers  in the binary . Note the serial number of  `.comment`   section header. In my system , it showed as  27 (may be different for your case)

`readelf -x 30 path/to/binary`  -> which will display the Hex dump of section '.comment'  . In that dump , you can see the compiler used for building the binary.

Answer (score 5):

`readelf` or `objdump` both can do this.

ELF file compiled by gcc will add `.note.ABI-tag` and `.note.gnu.build-id` sections. Both could displayed by:

```
objdump -sj .note.ABI-tag ELFFILE
objdump -sj .note.gnu.build-id ELFFILE
```

Option "s" means display full contents, "j" for indicate section name.
This style get hex contents of that sections.

The command `readelf -n` will show human-readable content of ELFFILE once.
option "n" means NOTES. Choose one as your like.

By the way, use `objcopy`, you can add your own section in elf file.

Comment: `readelf -n` worked for me - example output: ```Displaying notes found in: .note.gnu.build-id
  Owner                 Data size       Description
  GNU                  0x00000014       NT_GNU_BUILD_ID (unique build ID bitstring)
    Build ID: b88bae04e9043b71b329bac0ce2a2e5314183272
```

Comment: It's `.note.gnu.build-id`, not `.note.gnu-build-id`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [this clever script](https://pastebin.com/EU23iAvL) that counts the numbers of various CPU instructions used by the binary. It is based on parsing objdump output. Beware that it can take quite a long time to finish if you use it on a big binary.

Comment: Worth noting that it's x86 only.

Answer (score 1):

If you open an ELF binary in 7-zip, it will list the various sections within. From there, you can use the View context-menu option on say, the ".comment" section, to see the compiler's comments (eg. "GCC: (GNU) 4.9 20150123 (prerelease) Android clang version 3.8.256229  (based on LLVM 3.8.256229)").

Beware that the ".comment" section, if it exists, seems to start with a null character, so be sure to choose a viewer application for use within 7-zip that doesn't get confused by this (eg. tries to interpret the data as Unicode). Other sections that may exist and be of interest are ".note.*".

Comment: `readelf -p .comment <binary>` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42820439/695964

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth a lucky shot, depending on which program. Some programs will have this compiled in as information and accessible by some sort of version call (-V, --version, -Version, etc).  You may find any subset of those items you are looking for (including null set).  Here's a particularly fruitful example, Perl 5:

```
$ perl -V

Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 26 subversion 2) configuration:

  Platform:
    osname=linux
    osvers=4.15.15-1-arch
    archname=x86_64-linux-thread-multi
    uname='linux flo-64 4.15.15-1-arch #1 smp preempt sat mar 31 23:59:25 utc 2018 x86_64 gnulinux '
    config_args='-des -Dusethreads -Duseshrplib -Doptimize=-march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -Dprefix=/usr -Dvendorprefix=/usr -Dprivlib=/usr/share/perl5/core_perl -Darchlib=/usr/lib/perl5/5.26/core_perl -Dsitelib=/usr/share/perl5/site_perl -Dsitearch=/usr/lib/perl5/5.26/site_perl -Dvendorlib=/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl -Dvendorarch=/usr/lib/perl5/5.26/vendor_perl -Dscriptdir=/usr/bin/core_perl -Dsitescript=/usr/bin/site_perl -Dvendorscript=/usr/bin/vendor_perl -Dinc_version_list=none -Dman1ext=1perl -Dman3ext=3perl -Dcccdlflags='-fPIC' -Dlddlflags=-shared -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -Dldflags=-Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now'
    hint=recommended
    useposix=true
    d_sigaction=define
    useithreads=define
    usemultiplicity=define
    use64bitint=define
    use64bitall=define
    uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n
    default_inc_excludes_dot=define
    bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='cc'
    ccflags ='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'
    optimize='-march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt'
    cppflags='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include'
    ccversion=''
    gccversion='7.3.1 20180312'
    gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4
    longsize=8
    ptrsize=8
    doublesize=8
    byteorder=12345678
    doublekind=3
    d_longlong=define
    longlongsize=8
    d_longdbl=define
    longdblsize=16
    longdblkind=3
    ivtype='long'
    ivsize=8
    nvtype='double'
    nvsize=8
    Off_t='off_t'
    lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=8
    prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='cc'
    ldflags ='-Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib'
    libpth=/usr/local/lib /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.1/include-fixed /usr/lib /lib/../lib /usr/lib/../lib /lib /lib64 /usr/lib64
    libs=-lpthread -lnsl -lgdbm -ldb -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc -lgdbm_compat
    perllibs=-lpthread -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc
    libc=libc-2.26.so
    so=so
    useshrplib=true
    libperl=libperl.so
    gnulibc_version='2.26'
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs
    dlext=so
    d_dlsymun=undef
    ccdlflags='-Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/5.26/core_perl/CORE'
    cccdlflags='-fPIC'
    lddlflags='-shared -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector-strong'


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
  Compile-time options:
    HAS_TIMES
    MULTIPLICITY
    PERLIO_LAYERS
    PERL_COPY_ON_WRITE
    PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV
    PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT
    PERL_MALLOC_WRAP
    PERL_OP_PARENT
    PERL_PRESERVE_IVUV
    USE_64_BIT_ALL
    USE_64_BIT_INT
    USE_ITHREADS
    USE_LARGE_FILES
    USE_LOCALE
    USE_LOCALE_COLLATE
    USE_LOCALE_CTYPE
    USE_LOCALE_NUMERIC
    USE_LOCALE_TIME
    USE_PERLIO
    USE_PERL_ATOF
    USE_REENTRANT_API
  Built under linux
  Compiled at Apr 18 2018 22:21:20
  %ENV:
    PERL5LIB="/home/jhuber/perl5/lib/perl5"
    PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="/home/jhuber/perl5"
    PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base "/home/jhuber/perl5""
    PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/home/jhuber/perl5"
  @INC:
    /home/jhuber/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
    /home/jhuber/perl5/lib/perl5
    /usr/lib/perl5/5.26/site_perl
    /usr/share/perl5/site_perl
    /usr/lib/perl5/5.26/vendor_perl
    /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/lib/perl5/5.26/core_perl
    /usr/share/perl5/core_perl
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for compilation details of a static linked haproxy binary.

Using `-vv` gave me the details I needed:

```
$ ./haproxy -vv
HA-Proxy version 1.6.4 2016/03/13
Copyright 2000-2016 Willy Tarreau <willy@haproxy.org>

Build options :
  TARGET  = linux2628
  CPU     = generic
  CC      = gcc
  CFLAGS  = -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdeclaration-after-statement
  OPTIONS = USE_ZLIB=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_STATIC_PCRE=1

Default settings :
  maxconn = 2000, bufsize = 16384, maxrewrite = 1024, maxpollevents = 200

Encrypted password support via crypt(3): yes
Built with zlib version : 1.2.8
Compression algorithms supported : identity("identity"), deflate("deflate"), raw-deflate("deflate"), gzip("gzip")
Built with OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
Running on OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
OpenSSL library supports TLS extensions : yes
OpenSSL library supports SNI : yes
OpenSSL library supports prefer-server-ciphers : yes
Built with PCRE version : 8.38 2015-11-23
PCRE library supports JIT : no (USE_PCRE_JIT not set)
Built without Lua support
Built with transparent proxy support using: IP_TRANSPARENT IPV6_TRANSPARENT IP_FREEBIND

Available polling systems :
      epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
       poll : pref=200,  test result OK
     select : pref=150,  test result OK
Total: 3 (3 usable), will use epoll.
```